# PatternSyntaxException: String.replaceAll() android

Tags: android, replace

I want to remove all { } as follow:

```
String regex = getData.replaceAll("{", "").replaceAll("}", "");
```

but force close my app with log.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX
```

what have i done wrong ?

Comment: { is not a valid regexp.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `{`:

```
String regex = getData.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", "");
```

Comment: works, but it is not needed to use a regex for just matching a plain char

Answer (score 0):

Curly brackets are used to specify repetition in regex's, therefore you will have to escape them.

Furthermore, you should also consider removing all the brackets in one go, instead of called replaceAll(String, String) twice.

```
String regex = getData.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do **you don't need to use a regex**!

You can make use of the `replace` method instead to match specific chars, which *increases readability* a bit:

```
String regex = getData.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
```

Escaping the `\\{` just to be able to use `replaceAll` works, but doesn't make sense in your case